# «изломанные графы» -- значение

Tags: значение-слов

> История жизни на Земле — отнюдь не ровная прямая из точки А, поставленной три с половиной миллиарда лет назад, до точки Б в настоящем. Если бы такую линию удалось провести, нашему взору предстало бы нагромождение **изломанных графов**, где участки спокойного роста сменяются неожиданными резкими провалами. Эти короткие (конечно, в геологическом масштабе: десятки тысяч лет) кризисные отрезки называют периодами резкого сокращения биологического разнообразия или, попросту, массового вымирания.

Источник: [Компьютерра *Шестое массовое вымирание: если запустили, сможем ли остановить?*](http://www.computerra.ru/128422/sixth-me/)

Здесь «граф» это от английского слова [«graph»](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_of_a_function), не так ли? А «изломанный» значит с изгибами? К тому же, не совсем понимаю зачем автор сначала пишет про линию, чтобы практически сразу перейти к графам. Граф это же не прямая линия...

Comment: Я уточнил свой ответ. Подтвердите, пожалуйсста, что это перевод.

Comment: Я про термин, не про статью, а то Serg Z не так понял.

Comment: Если вы не про статью, то почему вы у меня спросили "Откуда вы знаете, что это он изначально написан на русском?" После моей фразы о том, что это не перевод, а написанный на русском ТЕКСТ. А потом свой коммент стерли. Ха-ха..) Забавный такой.

Comment: Вы так боитесь оказаться неправым, что подтираете комменты, чтобы этого не увидели? Зачем? Любой человек может ошибаться, даже такой знающий как вы. Будьте сильнее. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ответ](http://www.computerra.ru/128422/sixth-me/#comment-2141388444) автора статьи:

> С чего они взяли что это перевод?! :-)
>   Просто искал красивую формулировку, вот и всё (и - да, пробивал в Гугле, чувствовал, что педанты мимо не пройдут). Читайте: кривая, ломаная.

Comment: зачем тогда было вопрос задавать? И ведь автор так и не ответил, где он взял свой "красивую формулировку". Так что простите, я остаюсь при своем мнении.

Answer (score 0):

Наверняка - плохой перевод. Английское graph может значить что угодно, граф - не первое значение. Скорее всего речь идет об изломанных **линиях** (правильный термин - "ломаная").

user177103, я посмотрел. Здесь по контектсту подходит перевод "кривая" или просто "линия". Чтобы не искать специальные словари:

https://translate.google.ru/?hl=ru&tab=wT#en/ru/graph

(+)

Поскольку возникло "недопонимание", так назовем.
Я уверен, что здесь не может быть математического термина "граф", да Вы это и сами понимаете, раз спрашиваете "граф это же не прямая".

> чтобы практически сразу перейти к графам.

А он и не переходит к ним. Ваше недоумение вполне уместно. Там по смыслу - линия, автор пользуется плохим переводом термина, вернее всего прочитал что-то где-то и воспользовался ложным другом переводчика.

Comment: Это не перевод, а изначально написанный на русском текст. Автор - Евгений Золотов. А граф - конкретный термин из математики.

Comment: http://www.computerra.ru/128422/sixth-me/ Оттуда.

Comment: Я тут привел личную страничку автора текста и спрашивать, что он имел в виду, нужно у него. Вполне допускаю, что он использовал термин граф не вполне корректно. Но к чему молоть ступу в воде, если проще у него и спросить? А ваш вопрос ""откуда вы знаете, что изначально написанный на русском" относился к слову текст, а не термин. Что абсолютно очевидно из контекста и моей фразы "написанный на русском текст". А не термин. :)

Comment: А зачем мне спрашивать? Это дело автора вопроса.

Comment: Флудите пока что вы. А потом пишите "я свой флуд стер". Выложить скрин? Впрочем всем и так понятно, что между моими постами были ваши, которые вы потом почему-то удалили. Я же от своих слов не отказываюсь и не прячу их. И вам не советую. Отказ от своих слов всегда скверно выглядит. :)

Comment: Без комментариев.

Answer (score -1):

Граф - это математический термин из теории графов. 
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Вот личная страничка автора текста - http://vk.com/senti
Вы можете попробовать уточнить у него лично словоупотребление и значение.
Думаю, это будет оптимальнее, чем гадать и зря тратить время здесь в ненужных спорах.

Comment: Да есть такой термин, думаю, автор вопроса прекрачсно об этом знает.  Но термин "изломанный граф" здесь совершенно неприменим. Как и весь "граф".

Comment: А это уже вопрос к Евгению Золотову и тому, как он пользуется данным термином.

Comment: А мне это изначально неинтересно было. Я просто помог автору вопроса и все. Дальше он может копать сам.

Comment: Без комментариев.